# Input to nn.Linear(in_features=16*4*4, out_features=100)

Tags: python, pytorch

I am performing a CNN on the MNIST dataset with the following model:

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, mode):
    super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
    
    # Define various layers here, such as in the tutorial example
    # self.conv1 = nn.Conv2D(...)
    #First Convolution Kayer
    #input size (28,28), output size = (24,24)
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,6,5)
    self.reLU1 = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    self.MaxPool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)

    #Second Convolution Layer
    #input size (12,12), output_size = (8,8)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=6, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5)
    self.reLU2 = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    self.MaxPool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
    
    #Affine operations
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features = 16*4*4, out_features = 100)
    self.sig = torch.nn.Sigmoid()
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=100, out_features=10)
```

My forward pass is defined below.

```
def forward_pass(self, X):
    #Conv Layer #1
    X = self.conv1(X)
    X = self.reLU1(X)
    X = self.MaxPool1(X)
    #Conv Layer #2
    X = self.conv2(X)
    X = self.reLU2(X)
    X = self.MaxPool2(X)

    print(Tensor.size(X))
    #X = X.view()
    X = self.fc1(X)
    X = self.sig(X)
    X = self.fc2(X)
  
    return X
```

I get an error when trying to pass the Tensor into the fully connected `layer #1 (fc1)`. This is due to a mismatch in the `in_features` from my last Convolutional Layers.

When I print out the size of the tensor X before my fully connected layer I get `tensor.Size([10,16,4,4]).` Can anyone explain to me what would be the proper way to calculate the input to the first fully connected layer?

Answer (score 1):

Your classifier's input is shaped `(10, 16, 4, 4)`, discarding the first dimension which corresponds to the batch size, you end up with `16*4*4` elements. So this is correct, but the shape isn't: you need to flatten the spatial dimension before feeding the tensor to `fc1`. You can do using [`nn.Flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html):

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, mode):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        ## layer definitions
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()

    def forward(self, X):
        ## inference on CNN
        X = self.flatten(X)
        ## inference on fully-connected layers
```

Here is a inference example:

```
>>> model = ConvNet(mode=None)
>>> model(torch.rand(10, 1, 24, 24))
torch.Size([10, 10])
```

Side note please name your function `forward` instead of `forward_pass`, it is standard practice.